# FQL multiquery with HTTP GET - works in Graph API explorer but not anywhere else?

Tags: facebook, get, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

This FQL multiquery, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"posts":"SELECT actor_id,message,permalink,created_time,comments.count FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()","actors":"SELECT uid,name,pic_square,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #posts)"}
```

works perfectly in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), but when you put it straight in a browser, you get:

```
{
        "error": {
        "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.",
        "type": "OAuthException"
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Again something was deprecated by Facebook in their API?
I want to do an FQL multiquery using GET (actually using JSONP at the end) - **without** using the Javascript SDK.

By the way, I am sure it's not an authorization/access_token issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

URLencode the value of parameter `q`. `:`, `#` are special characters in a URL. Example:

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=%7B%22posts%22%3A%22SELECT%20actor_id%2Cmessage%2Cpermalink%2Ccreated_time%2Ccomments.count%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme%28%29%22%2C%22actors%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid%2Cname%2Cpic_square%2Cprofile_url%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20actor_id%20FROM%20%23posts%29%22%7D`

If your are using PHP use something like this:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . urlencode($my_fql_query);
```

Comment: BTW, I am getting following error for the same url: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Comment: Yeah, me too, though the real query that I need to use is different than the one I gave as an example. It is weird though that the example-query works in graph API explorer without this error.

Anyway, my real query works after properly url-encoding it.
I actually did try to use Javascript's URIEncode before, but it wasn't enough.
With "real" URL-encoding - it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?queries=...

Don't use 'q', use the param name 'queries'.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/), the parameter name that you're supposed to use is `q`, not `queries`: "You can issue a `HTTP GET` request to `/fql?q=query` where `query` can be a single fql query or a JSON-encoded dictionary of queries."